# jsp to servlet request.getParameter not working

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am a in a precarious situation! I have a html page with two frames.

```
1. xmldiff.html

<html>
 <head>
  <title>XML Diff</title>
</head>
<form name="xmldiff" method="post">
 <frameset rows="50%,50%">
   <frame name="left" src="XML1.jsp">
   <frame name="bottom" src="XML2.jsp">
 </frameset>
</html>

2. XML1.jsp

<form name="xml1">
XML 1:<br />
  <textarea name="xml1text" id="comments" style="width:100%;background-color:#D0F18F;" rows="50">
  Text Area 1!
  </textarea><br />
</form>

3. XML2.jsp

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function mysubmit()
{
document.xml3.text1.value=window.parent.left.xml1.xml1text.value;
}
</script>
<form name="xml2" action="/servlet/XMLDiffServlet" method="post" onSubmit="mysubmit()> 
Difference:<br />
  <textarea name="result" id="comments" style="width:100%;background-color:#D0F18F;" rows="22">${result}</textarea>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="text1" value="hello" />
</form>
```

And in the servlet XMLDiffServlet I am trying to retrieve the value of hidden button text1 by the following code -

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
{
    String origXML=req.getParameter("text1");

    req.setAttribute("result",origXML);
    String nextJSP = "/XML2.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
    rd.forward(req, resp);
}
```

So basically I am just trying passing the value of the hidden button and trying to display it in the result textarea. If I use XML2.jsp, I am not able to pass the value to the servlet, but I can retrieve any string from the servlet by using ${result}. On the other hand if I just rename XML2.jsp to XML2.html (without changing any code), I am able to pass the value of the hidden button to the servlet, but can't retrieve from it.

So how can I meet both the ends using a jsp - both pass the value and retrieve? Why request.getParameter is working from html and not for jsp? There are plenty of examples where this is working fine, but why not here? I created the onClick call in the submit button as well, but that stuff also didn't work. I am really baffled - can you please help me out?

Thanks
Nirmalya

Comment: So what is xml3 in document.xml3.text1.value a typo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should use onSubmit like

```
function mysubmit()
{
   document.xml3.text1.value=window.parent.left.xml1.xml1text.value;
   return true;
}
```

and in form

```
<form name="xml2" action="/servlet/XMLDiffServlet" method="post" onSubmit="return mysubmit()">
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your quick reply! But it's not working. Previously also I have tested this code, read  in an example that mysubmit() must "return true". But surprisingly this is not working for me! JSP is not able to pass the value to the servlet.

Comment: Wow! I found out the problem! My form was like `<form name="xml2" action="/servlet/XMLDiffServlet" method="post" onSubmit="return mysubmit()" enctype='multipart/form-data' >`. That enctype='multipart/form-data' is making all the difference. If it is present I am not able to pass the value to the servlet. Now I have to study more about it. Thanks John for your reply. @John